# Servlet is returning valid JSON data to JSP but ajax call is going to error function with 200 status code

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsp, servlets

Am returning a query from servlet to JSP in JSON format as below.

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(map3);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

It is a valid JSON data. I copied the value of "json' object here and verified in JSONLint.

Am making a ajax call in JSP and returning the data from servlet like below.

```
$.ajax({
url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/home',
type: 'POST',
data: { 
    'action': 'getBugReport',
    'dateString':document.getElementById("daterangePicker").value,
    'projectName': 'All'
    },
 complete: function(xhr, status) {
 if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
 console.log(error);
 alert(status);
 }
else {
console.log('It Works!');
}
},
success: function(responseJSON) {
    if(responseJSON!="" && responseJSON.data && responseJSON.data.length && responseJSON.data.length>0) {
  console.log("enter here");
}
```

},

```
error: function(err){
console.log(err);
}
});
```

It is always entering into error callback and printing the status code with 200. Am getting the data in responseText. This is the error object response in console.

readyState: 4
responseText: "{"1400312_PS-QA":"21 days","1399343_fixed":"6 days"
setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value )
state: ƒ ()
status: 200

Even complete: function is printing "it works" from the above code.

I searched entire stack overflow and tried with all the possibilities with dataType: json,jsonp contentType:applicaiton/json all the possibilities.

1 strange behavior i observed, when i pass dataType:text it will go inside success function() but responseJSON is not in expected format. It will break the if condition inside the success. When i debugged in servlet while writing the json data, its shows valid JSON in jsonlint.

Please someone help here, whats going wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try to let the jquery Ajax know, that it should expect a json return? `contentType: JSON,` in the same level as `type: 'POST',`

Comment: use `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @Stender tried your answer contentType: JSON.. it gives me jquery library error with 1.12 version. jquery-1.12.4.js:9129 Uncaught TypeError: (s.contentType || "").indexOf is not a function

Comment: yeah, forgot the " marks - it is a string

Comment: @Swati: Already tried with dataType: "json"... no luck :(

Comment: @Stender: Its going inside success but the response is responseJSON = "↵↵<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Tra"
Local
bug_id: undefined

Comment: can you share more code.. your code looks ok to me.